# How to replace a line which has multiple special characters with ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, escaping

Trying to replace a line which has multiple special characters, which gets interpreted as escape characters by ansible.

Tried using "\" and "." for every character, and tried using !unsafe.

```
- name: Update file
  replace:
    path: /some/file
    regexp: "*[0-9a-zA-Z._-]* )" #<<=== This is line to be replaced
    replace: "*[0-9a-z._-]* )"   #<<== With this
    backup: yes
```

Getting errors like:

raise error, v # invalid expression\r\nsre_constants.error: nothing to repeat\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1}

Answer (score 1):

Tried this and it worked:

```
regexp: '\*\[0-9a-zA-Z\._-\]\* \)'
replace: '*[0-9a-z._-]* )'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should escape the special characters with one backslash each:

```
regexp: '\*\[0\-9a\-zA\-Z\._\-\]\* \)'
```

And you should use single quotes.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It still kept giving error. I finally found a fix with multiple tries and error, and posted the answer above.

Comment: Nice, so my mistake was the backslash in front of the minus.